# Validate an Xml file with DTD in C

Tags: c, xml

Hi Can anybody tell me how to validate an XML file in c using DTD. I found answers in JAVA but I need the code in C.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/index.html), which can optionally validate against a DTD.  It also provides several ways of working with XML data.  On Linux, it's usually already installed, with development packages available through your package manager -- though the library is not Linux-specific.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C++, Xerces is a very good library. Powerful, easy to use.
http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/

Comment: can we write a simple c program to check for the validity of an xml file without using any external libraries. I am building a basic parser(my project), so I need to check for the validity of an xml. I dont need to check it for everything but main tags like, every line should start with < and end with >, something like dat